# Timed out waiting for connection while in state : CONNECTING

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a 3 node cluster for Kafka and zookeeper. Both Kafka and zookeeper cluster use same 3 machines. When I start the Kafka service, it fails to start if all 3 zookeeper servers are not up. Why is Kafka waiting for zookeeper cluster to be fully available ? I am not sure if I am overlooking g some setting. I am trying to launch zookeeper followed by Kafka one machine at a time. Error recieved Kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException

Comment: were you able to solve this?